# "Работал в полную силу" в случае, когда обстоятельства ограничиваются до желания

Tags: семантика, идиоматика

Можно ли употребить выражение "я работал в полную силу" в случае, если условия, необходимые для работы, сохранялись до определённого времени, а тот, кто выполняет работу, изначально планировал поработать меньше этого времени (речь идёт не о службе), а затем оказалось, что условия сохранились до тех пор, до которых планировал работать этот человек (то есть они были наличны меньше, чем предполагал он)?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что Ваш вопрос можно понять, но, думаю, на него всё равно можно ответить утвердительно из общих соображений.

Выражение "я работал в полную силу" построено грамматически правильно и отражает субъективное и/или эмоциональное отношение человека к своей работе. Вообще говоря, человек может употребить это выражение даже в том случае, если он сознательно лжёт. Впрочем, в подавляющем большинстве остальных случаев это утверждение тоже не будет абсолютно истинным из-за невозможности точно определить границы "полной силы" для конкретного человека.